# Duplicate non empty rows and add a new column in a Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a table with some data. The sheet in question does have empty rows.

`Sheet1`:

| date | id | name | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 31 | one | yes | 1 | 5 |
| 2022-02-01 | 26 | two | yes | 2 | 4 |
| 2022-03-01 | 150 | three | no | 3 | 9 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| [empty row] |  |  |  |  |  |
| [empty row] |  |  |  |  |  |

For each row, I have two metrics:

- `is good` = `col1 = yes`
- `% complete` = `col2 / col3`

I want to use an `ARRAYFORMULA` or something to split each row into two rows, one for each metric. So, for example, the expected output is:

| date | id | name | metric | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 31 | one | is good | true |
| 2022-01-01 | 31 | one | % complete | .2 |
| 2022-02-01 | 26 | two | is good | true |
| 2022-02-01 | 26 | two | % complete | .5 |
| 2022-02-01 | 150 | three | is good | false |
| 2022-02-01 | 150 | three | % complete | .33 |

I came up with this formula, but it puts a lot of blank lines in the middle since the source data has empty rows.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
    {
        IF(
            Sheet1!A2:A = "",
            ,
            {
                Sheet1!A2:C,
                Sheet1!D2:D = "yes"
            }
        );
        IF(
            Sheet1!A2:A = "",
            ,
            {
                Sheet1!A2:C,
                Sheet1!E2:E / Sheet1!F2:F
            }
        )
    }
)
```

My source data has a lot of rows, so I'm trying to find an efficient way to do this. I also considered ARRAYFORMULA with column concatenation (like an `unpivot`) but it's horribly slow because I have so much data.

My source data also has a lot of columns that translate to 10 different metrics/rows.

[image]

[image]

I thought to try something like this so I'm only processing rows with data, but it results in a `Formula parse error.`

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
    IF(
        Sheet1!A2:A = "",
        ,
        {
            Sheet1!A2:C,
            Sheet1!D2:D = "yes";
            Sheet1!A2:C,
            Sheet1!D2:D = "yes";
        }
    )
)
```

Updated: I have created a sheet with my example data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FgQ40zLd99f1xxkTtpwHStp91u5OFilyT_eigs0nYng/edit#gid=0.

Comment: Use `INDEX/COUNTA` instead of `IF(A:A="",,)`. That'll significantly reduce your  empty row problem.

Comment: [Your email address can be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Comment: Yeah. I know. My email address is public for other reasons so I'm okay with it. Thanks!

Comment: I know you know. But I'm doing it for other users who might not know and I want to stop this trend of sheet sharing. It's a battle.

Comment: I see. There must be a way to address this. Maybe a GAS app that lets users provide a sheet that makes it visible by others but hides the OP's address. Could be easy to implement. Thoughts?

Comment: There's effort on that part: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform but it still requires you to trust the script owners to do what they say they'll do.

Comment: I wonder if SO offers admin automation capabilities for users. A trigger for every new Q, if there is a Google Sheet link, replace it...

Comment: Possible, but have to gain  overwhelming [meta] support. If  this is a big tag like [python], it "may be" possible, but I don't think  that's possible from [google-sheets]. Even within Google sheets formula, I can't convince many users including player0 So my strategy here is to create awareness.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248604/discussion-between-imthenachoman-and-themaster).

Answer (score 2):

parse error is a result of having a semicolon after 2nd `yes`. change:

```
="yes";}))
```

to

```
="yes"}))
```

pro tip: don't use such JS syntax highlighting

---

### update 1:

```
=SORT({
 FILTER({Sheet1!A2:C, 
 IFERROR(N(Sheet1!A2:A)/0, "is good"), Sheet1!D2:D="yes"}, Sheet1!A2:A<>"");
 FILTER({Sheet1!A2:C, 
 IFERROR(N(Sheet1!A2:A)/0, "% complete"), Sheet1!E2:E/Sheet1!F2:F}, Sheet1!A2:A<>"")})
```

[image]

### update 2:

```
=LAMBDA(a, b, c, d, e, SORT({
 FILTER({a, IFERROR(N(b)/0, "is good"), c="yes"}, b<>"");
 FILTER({a, IFERROR(N(b)/0, "% complete"), d/e}, b<>"")}))
 (Sheet1!A2:C, Sheet1!A2:A, Sheet1!D2:D, Sheet1!E2:E, Sheet1!F2:F)
```

[image]

Comment: Removing the `;` still doesn't work as it only returns one set. What do you mean `JS syntax highlighting`? The formula at the bottom does not work. It is only returning 3 rows, instead of 6. And it seems to be mixing things...

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: I updated the question with a link.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan answer updated (again)

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan by "JS syntax highlighting" I meant https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmuni.png I mean there is nothing wrong with such formatting if you are used to it from different coding languages but GS is not really finetuned for this so a lot of silly mistakes usually ocours for ppl that use this - that's just my observation over the years ofc

Comment: Oh. Ha. Yeah, I just find it easier to read that way. The trailing `;` was a typo on my part.

Answer (score 1):

Use `REDUCE` to loop and create two rows for every row:

```
=REDUCE(
  {Sheet1!A1:C1,"metric","value"},
  Sheet1!A2:INDEX(Sheet1!A2:A,COUNTA(Sheet1!A2:A)),
  LAMBDA(
    a,c,
    {a;
    OFFSET(c,0,0,1,3),"is good", OFFSET(c,,3,1,1)="yes";
    OFFSET(c,0,0,1,3),"% complete", QUERY(OFFSET(c,0,4,1,2),"select E/F label E/F ''",0)
    }
  )
)
```

Comment: Nice. But why `QUERY` instead of `OFFSET(c,,4,1,1) / OFFSET(c,,5,1,1)`?

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan  Just wanted to do it as range instead of two offsets. Just a code style.  I also think query is faster(But some  users disagree).